# magento "assign to store view " IS MISSING in widget creation

Tags: magento

"assign to store view " option missing while creating a  new widget in Magento.I am creating a  widget to call a static block. but in cms static block i am unable to see the option

Answer (score 1):

You might have not created different store views from manage stores.
Untill that you wont get the option of assign to store view

Comment: how to create store views in magento store?

Comment: System->Manage Stores->Add new store and new store view as required